# How to detect a special char in string and modify this special word?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string, it may looks like this:

```
asjlfkajs alsdkfja s asldfkjas @abc dfasldkfj asldkfj las @nveweb dfasdlf asldfj.
```

I want to change any word started with @, to %@ %. for example,

```
@abc    change to    %@abc%
```

Can anyone show me an exmaple? I really have no idea about it, how to detect any word starting with @ and add % in the beginning and end of every such word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps simply:

```
str = string.Join(" ", str.Split()
                          .Select(w => w.StartsWith("@") ? "%" + w + "%" : w));
```

You need to add `using system.Linq;` at the top since the argument to `String.Join` is a LINQ query. `String.Split` without argument splits by [white-spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) which includes spaces, new-lines and tabs. At the end the `Join` will concat all with a space which means that you don't retain possible new-line or tab-characters.

However, the query itself does following, `str.Split()` returns all "words". `Enumerable.Select` projects a string which is either the orginal string (if the word doesn't start with `@`) or a new string which is wrapped by `%`.

**Update** if you want to retain the separator if they are at the beginning or at the end of words and don't want them to be wrapped also as in:

```
@abc.  --> wrong:  %@abc.% correct: %@abc%.
```

The you could use following method:

```
static readonly HashSet<char> WordSeparators = new HashSet<char> { ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', ' ', '-', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '"', '\'' };

static string WrapWithIfStartsWith(string input, string startsWith, string wrap, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || !input.StartsWith(startsWith, comparison))
        return input;
    else if(input.Length == 1)
        return string.Format("{1}{0}{1}", input, wrap);

    char first = input.First();
    char last = input.Last();
    bool firstIsSeparator = WordSeparators.Contains(first);
    bool lastIsSeparator = WordSeparators.Contains(last);
    if (firstIsSeparator && lastIsSeparator)
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}",
            first, wrap, input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2), last);
    else if (firstIsSeparator && !lastIsSeparator)
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}",
             first, wrap, input.Substring(1));
    else if (!firstIsSeparator && lastIsSeparator)
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{0}{2}",
            wrap, input.Remove(input.Length - 1), last);
    else
        return string.Format("{1}{0}{1}", input, wrap);
}
```

Now it's simple as:

```
string str = "blabalbal blabal @abc.";
str = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Select(w => WrapWithIfStartsWith(w,"@","%")));
```

Comment: As long as you're not worried about how to treat the `.` at the end.

Comment: @Rawling: it's a simple approach. The `Join` also replaces new-lines or tabs with spaces. However, maybe it's sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter! Is if difficult to deal with the comma . at the end? because it is possible to have something like this"blabalbal blabal @abc."

Comment: @user3821183: what is the desired result? Do you want to retain the dot but move it behind the `%`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yes, because the dot is not a part of the word, just like %@abc%.

Comment: @user3821183: i have edited my answer, have a look. Note that it's not testedt thoroughly.

Comment: @user3821183: there's a bug, it won't work perfectly if the word starts with a separator like `.` because then it wouldn't start with `$`, so currently the `firstIsSeparator`-part is pointless. However, i'm sure you know how to modify it so that it works according to your requirement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you so much for the excellent answer! that small bug is not serious, it is ok

Answer (score -1):

it will help

```
string str = "asjlfkajs alsdkfja s asldfkjas @abc dfasldkfj asldkfj las @nveweb dfasdlf asldfj.";
            string[] split = str.Split(' ');
            for(int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
            {
                if(split[i].StartsWith("@"))
                {
                    split[i] = "$" + split[i] + "$";
                }
            }
            string result = String.Join(" ", split);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
```